# Decompressing a netCDF file

Tags: compression, netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I have a compressed netCDF file called `in.nc` with a (_DeflateLevel=4). I want to decompress the file.

I've already tried using the following command but it doesn't change anything:

```
nccopy -d 0 in.nc out.nc
```

Here are the `in.nc` specifications:

```
time_counter = UNLIMITED ; // (12 currently)
    y = 552 ;
    x = 552 ;
variables:
    float Q16c(time_counter, y, x) ;
        Q16c:long_name = "Deep Sediment Particulate organic Matter" ;
        Q16c:units = "mg C/m2" ;
        Q16c:online_operation = "average" ;
        Q16c:interval_operation = "900 s" ;
        Q16c:interval_write = "1 month" ;
        Q16c:cell_methods = "time: mean (interval: 900 s)" ;
        Q16c:_FillValue = 1.e+20f ;
        Q16c:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
        Q16c:coordinates = "time_centered nav_lat nav_lon" ;
        Q16c:_Storage = "chunked" ;
        Q16c:_ChunkSizes = 1, 552, 552 ;
        Q16c:_DeflateLevel = 4 ;
        Q16c:_Endianness = "little" ;
```

Comment: Is the size of `in.nc` and `out.nc` the same?

Comment: Yes, both files have the same size!

Answer (score 2):

The way to decompress a compressed file with NCO is straightforward:

```
ncks -L 0 in.nc out.nc
```

p.s.: this method should work for the most common codecs, including DEFLATE, Zstandard, and Bzip2.

Comment: Great, thank you so much Charlie, your command has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to decompress files in cdo is

```
cdo -z zip_0 copy in.nc out.nc
```

If they are compressed using 2 byte **shorts** with an `add_offset` and `scale_factor` (e.g. ERA5 etc) then you can decompress those by converting to float like this

```
cdo unpack in.nc out.nc
```

or alternatively

```
cdo -b f32 copy in.nc out.nc
```